# ElasticSearch return non analyzed version of analyzed aggregate

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete, aggregate

I am having a problem implementing a autocomplete feature using the data in elastic search.. my documents currently have this kind of structure

```
PUT mainindex/books/1
{
  "title": "The unread book",
  "author": "Mario smith",
  "tags":  [ "Comedy", "Romantic" , "Romantic Comedy","México"] 
}
```

all the fields are indexed, and the mapping for the `tags` is a `lowercase,asciifolding` filter..

Now the functionality that is required is that if the user types `mario smith rom`..., I need to sugest tags starting with `rom`.. but only for books of `mario smith`.. this required breaking the text into components.. and I already got that part.. the current query is something like this ..

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "mario smith",
      "default_operator": "AND"
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "autocomplete": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "suggest",
        "order": {
          "_term": "asc"
        },
        "include": {
          "pattern": "rom.*"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and this returns the expected result, a list of word that the user should type next based on the query.. and the prefix of the word he is starting to type..

```
{
    "aggregations" : {
        "autocomplete" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
                {
                    "key" : "romantic comedy",
                    "doc_count" : 4
                },
                {
                    "key" : "romantic",
                    "doc_count" : 2
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

now the problem is that I can't present these words to the user because they are lowercase and without accents words liker `México` got indexed like `mexico`.. and in my language makes some words look weird.. if i remove the filters from the `tag` field the values are correctly saved into the index. but the pattern `rom.*` will not match because the user is typing in a diferrent case and may not use  the correct accents..

in general terms what is need is to take a filtered set of documents.. aggregate their tags, return them in their natural format.. but filter out the ones that dont have the same prefix. filtering them in a case/accent insentitive way..

PS: I saw some suggestions about having 2 versions of the field,one analyzed and one raw.. but cant seem to be able to filter by one and return the other..

does anyone have an idea, how perform this query or implement this functionality?